# docker compose Incorrect function

Tags: docker

I have a project with the followinf makeFile

```
# environments (put vars in .env/)
ifndef env
    env=dev
endif

include ./.env/${env}

# docker compose commands
build:
    docker compose build

run: run-db build
    docker compose up -d --remove-orphans

run-db:
    docker compose up --remove-orphans -d vsk-db

stop-db:
    docker compose stop vsk-db

stop-server:
    docker compose stop vsk-server

stop: stop-db stop-server

clean:
    docker compose down

logs:
    docker compose logs -f

clean-build: clean run logs

rerun: stop-server run
```

When I reinstalled docker desktop on windows and trying to execute this commands I get next error
read C:\Users\qwert\OneDrive\BUREAU\veryski.env: Incorrect function.

I verified folder .env the variables are recognized and I'm sure that the problem is in docker compose.
What should I do that the docker compose command works on windows ?

Answer (score 1):

I just experienced a similar problem, after I haven't touched one of my projects for a week, so my best guess is that is has to do something with an update either of VSC or Docker Desktop.

What solved it for me was to move the environment variable file out of the .env folder and deleting the folder entirely (Only after deleting the empty folder it worked again).

Then in your setup change:

```
include ./.env/${env}
```

to

```
include ./${env}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think some bug was introduced recently. This happened to me also exactly as you describe. Your (temporary) solution worked for me also. It is important to remember that we do need this to be sorted out as the whole idea was to hide the secrets from accidently reaching github (or similar). So in .gitignore we have .env .

Comment: True, however the folder where you store your environment variables (or .env file) is irrelevant as long as you update it accordingly in your .gitignore